# Update database using datagrid throws "dynamic sql generation is not supported against multiple base tables"

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, xaml, datagrid

In WPF datagrid when I'm try to update database using datagrid it show "dynamic sql generation is not supported against multiple base tables" 
Here is my code:

```
public productlist()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Bind();
}

MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["bd"].ConnectionString);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
MySqlDataAdapter da;
MySqlCommandBuilder cb;

private void Bind()
{
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        string qu = "SELECT product_category.product_cat_name, products.product_name, products.description, products.product_unit, products.company, products.image_name, products.product_code, vendors.name FROM product_category INNER JOIN products ON product_category.CategoryId = products.CategoryId INNER JOIN vendors ON products.vendor_id = vendors.vendor_id";
        MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand(qu, conn);
        da = new MySqlDataAdapter(qu, conn);
        da.Fill(ds);
        gridlist.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        conn.Close();
       // this.gridlist.Theme = ExtendedDataGrid.Themes.Media;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

private void update(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        cb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(da);
        da.Update(ds.Tables[0]);
        MessageBox.Show("Update successful");
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: how your update method is called ?

Comment: it work when data query is single. but when i am using join is show error